# Design pattern required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

A customer can place one order. Each order till its delivered goes through different phases.
Let's say there are many phases A, B, C, D, E. Moving through these phases will be done manually by a single client.
From A-> B (or) E , B -> C , C -> D (or) E

Each phase requires different inputs from the user to move to the next phase. All these inputs are different entities as modeled in the system.

In UI level I have a drop-down. If the current status is A then dropdown shows B and E. If B then C.
Value for dropdown is coming from the database from a master table. On choosing the different option I am showing different forms to the user using JQuery.

I have multiple ifs stacked up in my code both on .cshtml page and server side. Is there any better approach to do this?
Any design pattern that will help me in this scenario?

If I am doing anything wrong then please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This response is not asp specific and applies to any programming environment.

Your system has well defined phase and transitions between those phase. This is a good match for **State Pattern**.

The State Pattern provides for a **concrete Context Class** (holding the current State) an **abstract State Class** and a **concrete State sub-class for each state**. In your case you have obvious states A,B,C,D,E but you may also need a ENTRY state for initialisation and an EXIT state for cleanup.

For example state A will encapsulate all the logic to invoke the correct menus and forms for Phase A and also process the user input. State A is also responsible for making the transition to State B.

The flow of control through your application can be illustrated by a **state transition diagram**. Read about them here http://www.cs.unc.edu/~stotts/145/CRC/state.html

You can read about State Pattern with asp implementations here 
https://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern

The advantage of State Pattern is you can add new states as without complicated logic, and also you get rid of the big if/else block that would otherwise be needed to control the program flow. You will still have a decision to make in each state to decide the next state but that is very controllable.

Best way to learn State Pattern is to do some examples and start by applying to simple situations until you are confident to refactor your app.